# Writing Hello World program in seahorse and got this error

Tags: solana-program, python

could not find

```
import at /src + Seahorse.prelude.
    from Seahorse.prelude import *
```

I’m writing hello world in seahorse and i got this error, if anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you show the full source code you're trying to build, and what command you're running to build it?

Comment: yeah sure!

'''
from Seahorse.prelude import *

declare_id('')

@instruction
def hello(signer: Signer):
    print("GM SOLANA!!")
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo. You want that first line to be `from seahorse.prelude import *`

Lowercase s at the start of seahorse.

Comment: Yes, I got!!

Thanks for the help :)